# Local variable 'body' referenced before assignment - Python - build_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prettytable

Trying to send an email with Python build table. However, I'm experiencing the following error when I output the dataframe as a table. What is the issue here?

```
from pretty_html_table import build_table

riskDataFrame  = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)   
outputTable = build_table(riskDataFrame, 'blue_light')
```

Error is
**Unknown Error
local variable 'body' referenced before assignment**

File "C:\Python-3.9\lib\site-packages\pretty_html_table\pretty_html_table.py", line 141, in build_table
body = body + """

"""
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'body' referenced before assignment

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: I'm not seeing body referenced in your snippet

Comment: Adding the code that exactly shows the area, where the error message is.

Comment: According to build_table() source code (https://github.com/sbi-rviot/ph_table/blob/master/pretty_html_table/pretty_html_table.py) body variable is created inside loop. This means if you pass an empty df, the method will not enter the loop and body is undefined. Check if your df is empty before passing it to build_table()

Comment: @Harsh, Please add the above as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hello! I am the developer of this library, we added a patch that will return empty when the table is empty or undefined. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `build_table()` [source code](https://github.com/sbi-rviot/ph_table/blob/master/pretty_html_table/pretty_html_table.py),  variable `body` is created inside a loop. The loop is entered if the `DataFrame` passed in the argument is **not empty**

This means if you pass an empty `DataFrame` object in the `parameter`, the method `build_table()` never enters the `loop` and thus `body` remains `undefined`.

Check if your `df` is `empty` before passing it to `build_table()`

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it.